# I am not going to shade it

Tags: word-meaning

What is the meaning of the word shade in the following sentence. The word has a few meaning as a verb but it does not fit completely. Can I say it means " to hide"?

> She’s smoking either crack or meth, one or the other. I’m not going to
>   shade it,

http://www.foxnews.com/entertainment/2011/10/21/lindsay-lohans-dad-says-shes-smoking-meth-or-crack.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the word

> **shade**

is used to mean

> [**throw some shade** - To say a rude or slick comment towards another person with little or no one else catching the insult except who it was directed towards.](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Throw%20shade)